# Rails Module issue - undefined method 'validates_email' for User:class

Tags: ruby, module, ruby-1.9.3

I have a class called User, that needs to include a module.
The class looks like this:

```
require 'sequel'
require 'modules/validations'

class User < Sequel(..)
  many_to_one :country
  includes ::Validations

  validates_email(:email)
end
```

The module is defined in a subfolder called modules. It has been added to the $LOAD_PATH and Ruby is no complaining about the loading. The module looks like this:

```
module Validations
   def validates_email(attr, options = {})
       email = super.email
   end
end
```

The error I am getting is :
**undefined method 'validates_email' for User:class**

What am I missing to make this work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use modules to define class methods you should use the `extends` method.

```
class User < Sequel(..)
  extend ::Validations
  validates_email(:email)
  ...
end
```

I suggest reading this article: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/

Comment: This solved the problem for including the module thanks. Can I access the variables from my class in this module?

Comment: You should be able to access them normally

Comment: Shouldn't this be "extend," not "extends?"

Comment: Yes, it should have been. Fixed